# Determine convergence of power series of triple integral

Tags: integration, power-series

Does this power series converge? I think it does, but how to prove it?

$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \int \int \int  3^{-i}\left(\cos(\pi x) + \cos(\pi y) + \cos(\pi z) \right)^idxdydz,
$$

where the integrals are all over $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This converges absolutely. To show this it's enough to show

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{[0,1]^3} \left(\frac{|\cos\pi x| + |\cos\pi y| + |\cos\pi z|}{3} \right)^k\,dV <\infty.$$

By the monotone convergence theorem, we can bring the sum inside to see this sum equals

$$(1)\,\,\,\,\int_{[0,1]^3}\left(\frac{1}{1-(|\cos\pi x| + |\cos\pi y| + |\cos\pi z|)/3}\right)\,dV.$$

Let $f(x)=(|\cos\pi x| + |\cos\pi y| + |\cos\pi z|)/3.$ Then $f=1$ at $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1),$ and $f<1$ everywhere else. It's enough to show that for any small $a>0,$ ($1$) converges if $[0,1]^3$ is replaced by $[0,a]^3.$ That's because of symmetry: the singularity of the integrand at $(1,1,1)$ is just like that at $(0,0,0).$ Everywhere else we have a walk in the park.

Now $\cos x \le 1-x^2/4$ for small $x.$ So if $a$ is small enough,

$$ \int_{[0,a]^3}\left(\frac{1}{1-f(x,y,z)}\right)\,dV \le \int_{[0,a]^3}\left(\frac{C}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)\,dV$$

for some constant $C$ (I think $C=12$ works). Now we're in business because $1/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is locally integrable on $\mathbb {R}^3.$ That does it, and I would love it if there's a simpler way to see it.